# What is the difference between ы and и?

Tags: произношение

All other Russian vowels come in pairs, but this pair seems a bit special.
So, how does one pronounce ы and и?

Comment: Shortly speaking, the back of your tongue goes up when you pronounce "И", and it remains low when you say "Ы"

Comment: the nature of Ы and И is the very controversial part of the 100 year academic discussion. you can read the arguments of [ЛФШ](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0) (Leningrad Phonology School) and [МФШ](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0) (Mo

Comment: That's the sound you make when somebody is strangling you :)

Comment: A girl in this video explains [how to pronounce Ы](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sB61Fi1LluY).

Answer (score 19):

All vowels in Slavic languages come in three varieties: open, closed and iotized (closed following the palatal approximant `j`)

Russian phonetics requires that all open vowels follow non-palatalized (hard) consonants, and all closed vowels follow palatalized consonants. Openness is not a distinguishing attribute of a Russian vowel (unlike, say, English *and / end*). So normally all vowels in the alphabet come in pairs: open and iotized, but an iotized vowel following a hard consonant actually makes it soft and is pronounced closed instead:

```
a / я
о / ё
у / ю
э / е
```

`и / ы` is a notable exception: this is a closed/open pair. In Russian alphabet (unlike, say, Ukrainian), there is no separate letter for iotized `и` (because there is no such sound in the language), so it was required to mark the palatalization of the previous consonant.

`Ж` and `Ц` do not have soft counterparts in Russian, so `цы` is only written historically in some Russian words (*цыпленок, цыган, цыкать*) and in endings (*щипцы*) but pronounced `цы` even for words written with `ци` (*вакцина, акция*). `жы` is never written this way (though always pronounced exactly like this).

`Ч` does not have a hard counterpart, and there are no words with `чы`.

`Ш` and `Щ` (in common pronunciation) are hard and soft versions of the same consonant, so they are always written `ши`, `щи`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, do you mean "open" and "close" as in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_vowel_chart_with_audio ?
If not, where can I find more information?

Comment: @jrouquie: I've just calqued Russian linguistic terms: http://literary_terms.academic.ru/394/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8 The difference is as between `u/ü`, `a/ä` etc in German.

Comment: +1: Finally I understood why полиция is pronounced in that way! It is actually полицыя!

Comment: Can u please tell, in the pair and/end which one is open and which is closed?

Comment: So does ы have a slight й offglide?

Answer (score 10):

### Ы

- is pronunced /ɨ/ ("roses", or polish "y")
- is used if and only if it follows a hard consonant

### И

- is pronunced /i/ ("machine") or /ɪ/ ("bin").
- palatalize the preceding consonant
- is not preceded by /j/ in isolation
- is pronunced /ɨ/ when following ж, ш, ц (because /i/ would be hard to pronunce)

Comment: Is it your answer or is it still a part of your question?

Comment: This is "what I have collected on wikipedia", so this is already some answer. If you want, you can read the question as "if this is not true, please correct me".

Comment: By the way, why downvote? I have seen another question which already contained an answer and was criticized for that, so I thought this would be the right way to post. Or is this answer wrong? (If so, please edit Wikipedia ;-)

Comment: I didn't downvote) It's just that you were asking about their status as a pair of sounds, and you gave an analysis of them, but you didn't draw a conclusion, and that was what startled me, I guess. That was why I asked.

Comment: Some notes. 1) Ы is pronounced as [ɯ] according to some sources; really the difference is too small. 2) I applaude to your treating of combinations like жи, ши, because it's more correct than usual treating their vowel as "ы" (but often it's [ɪ] instead of [ɨ]). But please note that average Russian speaker mind differs и/ы on consonant palatalization, so he (she) would say it's "ы".

Answer (score 5):

There is a sound file on [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_central_unrounded_vowel) Wikipedia page for 'Ы'.
And [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B8#Pronunciation_2) you can listen how to pronounce 'И'.

Answer (score 2):

Ы and И are allophones, that is they specify the same phoneme. The only difference between them is in that И softens the preceding consonant while Ы does not.

Thus any detectable difference in pronunciation is due the influence of the preceding consonant which is either soft or hard.

Comment: really? And what about just shouting out loudly - "ИИИИИИИИИИИИИИ" or "ЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫ" - there's no preceding consonant at all. Or "ЙЫЫЫЫЫЫЫ" and "ЙИИИИИ" - do you claim that Й softens? )))))

Comment: What is "ЙЫЫЫЫЫЫЫ"? It is impossible to pronounce. You either get Й hard (something like Ukrainian Г) or pronounce "ЙИИИИ". Anyway if you claim И and Ы are different phonemes, demonstrate the minimal pairs.

Comment: It is possible to pronounce though is not typical for russian. Nevertheless you are wrong, we can not simplify like that. It's NOT all about preceding consonant - there's not always such consonant.

Comment: @shabunc It is impossible to pronounce. "there's not always such consonant" - Russian has no native words starting with "Ы". And those borrowed geographical names pronounced the same way as if they were started with "И". Again if you think they are different phonemes, give an example of a minimal pair.

Comment: давайте я по-русски скажу, если вы русским владеете. Я знаю, что такое палатализация. Но ёлки-палки - вы что, правда не можете произнести ЫЫЫЫЫЫ - просто, безпримесно, просто ЫЫЫЫЫ - вы что, правда не чувствуете разницу по сравнению с ИИИИ? Ну нет такого слова - и что - произнести вы можете?

Comment: >And those borrowed geographical names pronounced the same way as if they were started with "И" - that's wrong. Иваново и Ываново sounds differ for any native speaker.

Comment: There is no such word "Ываново" so it cannot sound differrently. As I already said There are no minimal pairs for Ы and И in Russian. This means that they specify the same phoneme.

Comment: "Ну нет такого слова - и что - произнести вы можете?" А ёёёёёёёёёё и йооооооооо по-вашему, тоже по-разному звучит?

Comment: Please move this discussion into the chat.

Comment: @Anixx - last thing I want to quote - The six-vowel view, held by the Saint-Petersburg (Leningrad) phonology school, points to several phenomena to make its case: Native Russian speakers' ability to articulate [ɨ] in isolation (for example, in the names of respective letters, ⟨и⟩ and ⟨ы⟩) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_phonology. As for ёёёёёё and йоооооо - it is completely separate case, nevertheless you'll be surprised, there IS difference there as well. Check out sounds that stands for french eu and eau for example. И вы так и не ответили различаете ли вы на слух Ы и И)

Comment: @Quassnoi - мы всё )

Comment: @shabunc как я уже сказал, предыдущая согласная как правило, воздействует на гласную. Это относится не только к и/ы, но и к э, о, а. Тем не менее, оба варианта произношения гласной являются аллофонами и не образуют различных фонем.

Comment: @Annix, нет вы не так сказали, вы сказали что это один и тот же звук (specify the same phoneme), и что вся разница (the only difference) в смягчении - ну что кроме ленинградской школы вами привести в качестве иллюстрации? Глаголы икАть и Ыкать? И вы всё-таки всё равно не ответили - вы на слух Ы и И отличаете? Каким образом фонема i и фонема ɨ не образуют различных фонем, ну каким? А впрочем, больше я вас убеждать не буду. Это как объяснять что есть синий цвет и зелёный - а тебе - а нет такого цвета. Вас не переубедить видимо. И тем не менее - расслабьтесь и скажите ЫЫЫЫЫ. И прислушайтесь)

Comment: Я сказал, что это одна и та же фонема. "Глаголы икАть и Ыкать?" ЛОЛ. Как насчет глаголов ŋекать, ɦекать и ðекать? "Каким образом фонема i и фонема ɨ не образуют различных фонем, ну каким?" - Почитайте что такое фонема сначала, лол.

Comment: вы не отвечаете на заданный вам 10 раз вопрос)))

Comment: Я уже вам ответил, что предыдущая согласная окрашивает гласную. [ɨ] и [i] в русском языке в начале слова являются аллофонами, любое слово, начинающееся на и- можно произнести с начальным [ɨ], от этого смысл слова не изменится.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4023/discussion-between-shabunc-and-anixx)

Comment: Anixx, [Ги](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ги_(одежда)) — одежда, Гы — неологизм, выражает разные оттенки смеха. Это раз уж вам так нужен пример. Но он не нужен. @shabunc правильно говорит и ы́кать/и́кать вполне достаточно. Ключевым является не только способность различить эти звуки, но и сопоставить записи, снова воспроизвести, и передать однозначно другому человеку это различие и устно и письменно.

Comment: Некорректным является пример gэкать и ɣэкать/ɦэкать. Тут дело и в невозможности записать средствами своего алфавита, и в проблеме передачи другому человеку. Причём в укр/бел языках этой проблемы нет и ґэкаць и гэкаць — 2 разных фонемы. (если не в бел. то в укр. [точно](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/what-are-the-types-of-ge-sounds-in-the-east-slavic-languages))

Comment: @yalov невозможность записать никак не связана с фонемностью того или иного звука.

Comment: @yalov "Ги — одежда, Гы — неологизм, выражает разные оттенки смеха." - это не пример, данные слова отличаются мягкостью согласной.

Answer (score 1):

Deciding phonemes by minimal pairs is quite logical. In English for example, there are no minimal pairs between [h] and [ŋ]. Thus, they are the same phoneme. It makes no difference that any child can tell the difference, and no-one can see any the similarity between the two. 
   Similarly, И and Ы are allophones of the same phoneme, even though all speakers of Russian are consciously aware of producing them separately.

Comment: I doubt ŋ is a phoneme in English: it seems to be an allophone of [n].

Comment: The argument was made by Chomsky and Halle in their English phonology - it closely follows your argument in your own answer and the comments to it that there are no minimal pairs between И and Ы (i.e. no words which differ in only this contrast). This answer could even be regarded as a duplicate, though the tone and the conclusion ("any child can hear the difference") is quite distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Put it crudely, tell `[u]` as in the word `put`, but make your lips as if you want to say `[i:]` as in the word `deep`. The difference between `и` and `ы` is in that `ы` is close **central** unrounded vowel, but `и` is close **front** unrounded vowel. Dorsum of tongue is raised not in the front but in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

English speakers' pronounce is closer to Ы when saying such words as vIsion, to lIve, clIck, etc., but native Russian Ы sound is more dull and wide.
In fact, Russian clear pronounce of И is rarely heard in English speech, in such words as Even, lEAve, nEAt, snEAk, etc.